# DatePicker Viewの描画が即時に反映されなくなる

Tags: java, android, android-layout

AndroidでDatePickerのCalendarViewを使用しています。

```
android:calendarViewShown="true"
android:spinnersShown="false"
```

しかし、しばらく使っていると描画が即時に反映されなくなります。

日付をタップしてもその日が選択状態の表示になりません(`OnDateChangeListener.onSelectedDayChange`は呼ばれているが描画のみ反映されていない状態)。
スクロールした瞬間に描画が更新され、タップした日付がやっと選択状態の表示になります。

ちなみに、ダイアログではなく、ボタンをトリガーにDatePickerを含む親のRelativeLayoutのvisibilityを`"visiblity"`と`"invisible"`に切り替えることで表示非表示を切り替えています。
いろいろ調べましたが解決には至りませんでしたので、何かアドバイスお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

onSelectedDayChange の中で、

```
view.invalidate()；
```

しても駄目でしょうか？